# DataBase linking Error to the Application

Tags: java, mysql, database, varchar

I have been trying to run my project which is a web application that takes excel sheet as input and processes the data. Up until recently the execution was taking place smoothly but only today morning that i am getting the below error,do help

Exception in PoolingDAO ==> insertClass() :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'item_codes' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate   
at com.Fidoop.DAOFactory.PoolingDAO.insert_to_mbill(PoolingDAO.java:471)
at com.Fidoop.util.GetInvoiceRead.Itemlistread(GetInvoiceRead.java:63)
at com.action.user.UploadFileMaster.doPost(UploadFileMaster.java:291)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

NEW CONNECTION CREATED
Vector :[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@75c5a4]
Destroy Connection
Removing Duplicate words:

Comment: Seems pretty obvious: `Data too long for column 'item_codes' at row 1`. Your incoming data for the column 'item_codes' is longer than the specified size of that column. Maybe the incoming data for that column was in the right size before, but now it is changed somehow.

Comment: the size i have given for item_codes is varchar(10000)and in the spreadsheet the value in that row is 17654

Comment: You are saying it yourself: `17654 > 10000`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's the whole point, that is I reduced the column value to less than 10000 and the above error is still present.

Comment: Character encoding issues? Even with less than 1000 characters, your *byte* size can be much *more*. Check out Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'item_codes' at row 1`

This error is coming from MySQL because whatever you're trying to persist is too large for the given field `item_codes`. You have several options to mitigate this

- field length on that table *
- adjust the character length in the spreadsheet
- programatically trim the length of the input.

Comment: this is the first line of the error
>Exception in PoolingDAO ==> insertClass() :
if i visit the function in the java file , it is present inside catch : 
catch (Exception e)
 {
 System.out.println("Exception in PoolingDAO ==> insertClass() : ");
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

Comment: so how would i go about

Comment: I'd recommend using a debugger or log out your values to verify if your program is behaving correctly.